# functions to create term and child terms

Tags: taxonomy, terms

I've got a MySQL table with car makes and models. I'm using php to pull the data and enter it into terms in WordPress. What WordPress function would I use to create the term and then the taxonomy `ua-auction-category`. Then the child term for the model.

Example: `Ford -> Fusion`. Hope I was clear enough.

Any questions let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a taxonomy, you should use [`register_taxonomy()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy). This function accepts three arguments:

```
 <?php register_taxonomy( $taxonomy, $object_type, $args ); ?>
```

The documents on the codex are plenty self explanatory.

Now, to insert a term into a taxonomy, you can use [`wp_insert_term()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term). Again this function accepts 3 arguments:

```
<?php wp_insert_term( $term, $taxonomy, $args = array() ); ?>
```

You can check the codex page for instructions.